# Let $G$ be any group. Set $M(G)$ to be the intersection of all subgroups of finite index in $G$. Prove that $M(G)$ is normal.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be any group. Set $M(G)$ to be the intersection of all subgroups of finite index in $G$. Prove that $M(G)$ is normal.

It seems that we need to prove for any $x\in M(G)$, $gxg^{-1}$ belongs to every subgroup of finite index. But how to prove it?

Comment: Remark that if $H$ is a subgroup of finite index, so is $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: I would bet that it's even characteristic.

Comment: @Robert i f you can prove that automorphisms carry groups of finite index to groups of finite index, then yes. The proof provided can be adopted.

Comment: @AndresMejia That has to be true, right? The automorphism gives a bijection between the set of cosets of a subgroup and set of cosets of the image of that subgroup under the given automorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if $x$ belongs to every subgroup of finite index, then $gxg^{-1}$ does as well, since for each $H \subset G$ of finte index, we have that $gxg^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$ which is also finite index, so $x \in gHg^{-1} \implies x=g^{-1}yg$ for some $y \in H$, and hence $gxg^{-1}=gg^{-1}yg^{-1}g=y \in H$,  and since $H$ was arbitrary, $gxg^{-1}$ belongs to every finite index subgroup.